# Trace32 window data is truncated when printed out to a file

Tags: trace32

I am trying to print a memory range window that shows the value of an array of string to a file using

```
winprint.data.View %Var v.address("sortData0.strings")
```

the issue is when I check the file, I find it as follows

```
________address|_data|value_____________|symbol
SD:3000A11C| 30   sortData0.strings[.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      SD:3000A11D|
SD:3000A11D| A5    |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       SD:3000A11E|
SD:3000A11E| 00    |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       SD:3000A11F|
SD:3000A11F| 30    +
```

the values seem to be truncated. When I opened the window, it looked like
[image: window scrrenshot]
It seems that this is happening because the columns are initially collapsed. How can I solve that? I need to that using the practice commands without any GUI interactions because that'll be a part of an automated test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command [WinTABS](https://www2.lauterbach.com/pdf/ide_ref.pdf#M8.newlink.WTABS) to set the column width before opening/exporting the window. Please try something like this:

```
WinTABS 10. 100.  
WinPrint.Data.View %Var Var.ADDRESS("sortData0.strings")
```